# Animate intro page/background to next page

Tags: javascript, php, css, animation

I would like to be able to animate a simple intro page/background to the next page with just CSS or little javascript if needed, with an easy PHP inclusion. When link is clicked it loads all the content: header(menu) / content / footer, which can be called the 'startpage'.

I know how to just put some keyframes animations on the content that is loaded, but i don't want the menu (header) to animate more that first time only the content part. Maybe the best thing to do is to not go to the startpage, but already have it loaded underneath the intro part and animate the intro into the startpage. I read about cubic-bezier with this in mind.

**CSS:**

```
a {
 color: inherit;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
 transition: color 0.3s;
}

.intro {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  top: 48%;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18vw;
  color: white;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2; 
 }

.bg {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: black;
  z-index: 1;
 }

a:hover + .bg {
 background: white;
 -webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
 transition: background 0.3s;
}

.intro:hover  {
 color: black;
}
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/header.php') ?>

<a href="/start" class="intro">INTRO TEXT OR LOGO</a>
<div class="bg"></div>

<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/footer.php') ?>
```

Comment: I added a PHP class script to the menu items and content separte so you can animated them only when page is set to startpage with CSS: class="<?php if($page=='About'){echo 'current-effect';}?>" which works fine, not sure this is the best way but it works using simple keyframe animation.

Comment: I tried reading this question couple of times and I still don't understand what **exactly** you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: FadeOut from the intro page which is black and white depending when hovering the intro text/logo to next page which is loaded separately.

Comment: Have got it working with adding a class (bit of PHP) with keyframes animation (fadeIn) on those elements when entering just the startpage